# Missing Symlink in Open SSL

Tags: system-installation, software-installation

I experienced a problem setting up a new system (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, openssl 3.0.2-0ubuntu1.8) because libssl.so could not be found until I added a symlink from "libssl.so" to libssl.so -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.3.

Is the lack of a symlink a bug in the openssl or some other package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link is provided by the `libssl-dev` package - since it should only be needed by `ld` when building software from source.

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 11 Apr 17 14:12 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so -> libssl.so.3

$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
libssl-dev:amd64: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so
```